# How do I calculate $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, infinity

I've seen a handful of exercises like this:

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x})$$

I've never worked with limits to infinity when there is some arbitrary number $a$. I am not given any details about it.

Apparently the answer is $0$. How was that conclusion reached?

---

My *guess* is that since $x = +\infty$, the result of $x + a$ will still be $+\infty$ so we would have $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x} = 0$.

But that doesn't convince me. For starters,  we don't know what $a$ is: it could be $-\infty$ or something, so $\infty - \infty$ would be indeterminate...

Comment: The trick here is to multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: @SimonS well, I would have $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}}$$ But wouldn't that cause the same problem? If $a = -\infty$.

Comment: $-\infty$ is not a real number. But this does work for every real number $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an expression like that is written, the common assumption (in a Calculus course) is that $a$ is some real number.

The symbols $\infty$ of $-\infty$ do not represent real numbers and cannot be treated as such. Expressions like $x\to\infty$ and $\lim f(x)=\infty$ have precise meanings that do not involve the symbol $\infty$.

In this case,
$$
\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x=(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x)\,\frac{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}
=\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}.
$$
For whatever number $a$ is, the expression on the right goes to zero as $x\to\infty$. To argue formally, note that 
$$
\left|\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}\right|=\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}\leq\frac{|a|}{\sqrt x}.
$$
For a given $\varepsilon>0$ (that we think as small), if $x>a^2/\varepsilon^2$, then 
$$
\frac{|a|}{\sqrt x}<\frac{|a|}{|a|/\varepsilon}=\varepsilon.
$$
This means that, if $x$ is big enough we can guarantee that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}$ it is as close to zero as we want.

Comment: Hmm...... So it's not really about replacing $x$ with $+\infty$, but rather consider what happens as $x$ keeps growing? I can see that as $x$ grows, the denominator will obviously grow further and the whole division will come closer to $0$.

Comment: Exactly. I'll edit the answer with the details.

Comment: Would it have been acceptable to just say "if we grab the highest exponents we have $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x}$ = 0"? Given that $a$ is some real number, we could ignore it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Usually when solving limits with infinity, I take the highest exponents. For example, with $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+3}{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}$$ I would just take $$\frac{2x}{x}$$ Because they are the "highest exponents", resulting in $2$. For this exercise, given $$\sqrt{x+a} - \sqrt{x}$$, can I "take the highest exponents" like $$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x}$$ and conclude that $$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x} = 0$$? (Completely ignoring $a$ since it has no $x$ with exponent).

Comment: No, that doesn't work. For example, try your "technique" on $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}-\sqrt{x^2}=\frac12$$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x^{3/2}}-\sqrt{x^2}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

**METHOD 1:**

We can write

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x+a}&=\sqrt{x}\left(1+\frac ax\right)^{1/2}\\\\
&=\sqrt{x}\left(1+\frac{a}{2x}+O\left(\frac ax\right)^2\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{x}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{x}}+O\left(\frac 1x\right)^{3/2}
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{a}{2\sqrt{x}}+O\left(\frac 1x\right)^{3/2}\to 0$$

as $x\to \infty$.

---

**METHOD 2:**

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}&=\left(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}\right)\,\frac{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}}\\\\
&=\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x}}\to 0
\end{align}$$

as $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt x)\frac{(\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x)}{(\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+a-x}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}$$
$$=a\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt x}=a(0)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You may write
$$
\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}=\left(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}\right)\frac{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x}}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{x+a} + \sqrt{x}}
$$ then it becomes easier to obtain your limit as $x \to \infty$.