# limit of $\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n}$ without Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Let $a_n = \sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n}$ be a sequence where $k\in \Bbb R^+$.  Find the limit of $a_n$.

I want to evaluate this limit without doing a series expansion of the terms (it seems like overkill).  Intuitively, it should be $0$ because as $n$ becomes large the $k$ becomes insignificant.  But how can I show it?  I can't just factor out $\sqrt{n}$ because $$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n}}-1)$$ goes to $\infty\cdot 0$.

Comment: Try multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Awesome.  I knew there'd be a simple solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\vphantom{b} x+a}-\sqrt{\vphantom{b} x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457129/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/)*)

Comment: So it is.  Thanks @Workaholic.

Comment: @BobbieD You're welcome, be sure next time to use [*Approach0.xyz*](https://approach0.xyz/) before asking a question to know whether it was already made.

Comment: Will do. :-)$ $

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n})=(n+k)-n=k$.

Hence we have that $\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n}= \frac{(\sqrt{n+k}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n})}{(\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n})}=\frac{k}{\sqrt{n+k}+\sqrt{n}},$ which goes to zero since the numerator is constant and the denominator goes to infty.

Comment: Minor quibble: the numerator is constant, and the denominator goes to infinity.