# Showing that $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, radicals

Hey guys I'm really struggling to prove this, any help would be appreciated!!

"Show that $\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. 
(Make use of $u - v = \frac{u^2 - v^2}{u + v})$."

Intuitively I understand as it basically becomes infinity - infinity once $x$ becomes sufficiently large, however I cannot seem to write a justifiable proof.

Comment: Substitute $u=x^2+a^2$ and $v=x$ and use the suggested formula. The nominator will be $a^2$ while the denomintator still contains $x$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457129/how-do-i-calculate-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtxa-sqrtx)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x & \\& =\dfrac{(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}\\& =\dfrac{x^2+a^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}\\& =\dfrac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}.\end{align}

Comment: So multiplying by the conjugate and then "dividing through by x^2" in your last step would yield the result?

Comment: I have not divided by $x^2.$ I have just cancelled $x^2:$ $\color{red}{x^2}+a^2-\color{red}{x^2}=a^2.$

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x=0$$

To do this, we use $$\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x=\frac{x^2+a^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}$$

Now, the limit is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

---

Let $u=\sqrt {x^2+a^2} $ and $v=x $.